# Sorting the order of entire columns in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How can I sort this 3,20 ndarray by column? The `np.sort()` doesnt seem to do what I think it does. I want to turn this:

```
                                                                 a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

into this:

```
                                   a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Note: **the columns are kept intact** - see column `a`. They are sorted first by the first element in the column, then the second,  then the third.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean? it doesnt correlate? I would just like to sort entire columns in a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)?

```
>>> arr[:,np.lexsort(arr[::-1])]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer could you explain it a little? Im confused why the `arr[::-1]` needs to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

Make each line a tuple and use it as a sort criterion:

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

np.array(sorted(a, key=tuple))

Out:

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it has intuitive/readability appeal

Comment: This will be very slow for medium to large arrays.

Comment: @Ophion can you perhaps comment on the `lexsort` answer clarifying for a new person :]